# UIGestureRecognizer with a touch moving off UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UILongPressGestureREcognizer` with a minimum press length of 0 seconds. On `UIGestureRecognizerStateStart` I alter the UIView. On `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, I run the code for what ever the press is suppose to do.

```
-(IBAction)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    
    static NSTimer *timer = nil;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // alter look of UIView
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // do something
        // change look back to original state
    }
}
```

I am running into an issue where if the touch starts on the `UIView` and if the touch is dragged outside of the `UIView` and is lifted, the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` still fires.

I need to be able to handle a touch inside the `UIView`, the user drag outside of the `UIView` and to cancel it.

I know a `UIButton` can do it, but it does not fulfill all the needs I have.

How can I cancel a touch if the touch is dragged outside of the `UIView`?

Answer (score 1):

Add checking of touch location. This method can be heplfull.

> - (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view